# Inequality in overlap of quantum states

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

For quantum states $\vert\psi_1\rangle, \vert\psi_2\rangle, \vert\phi\rangle$, is it true that:

$$\tag{1}\langle \phi\vert\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1\vert\phi\rangle\langle \phi\vert\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2\vert\phi\rangle + \langle \phi\vert\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2\vert\phi\rangle\langle \phi\vert\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1\vert\phi\rangle \leq \langle \phi\vert\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_2\vert\phi\rangle + \langle \phi\vert\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_1\vert\phi\rangle.$$

My argument is that each number $c_i = \langle\phi\vert\psi_i\rangle$ is a complex number with modulus smaller than 1 since it is the square root of a probability. So we have to show:

$$2|c_1|^2|c_2|^2 \leq c_1c_2^* + c_1^*c_2\tag{2}.$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\langle a | b \rangle$ is usually a scalar, so you can move such objects around on the left side, and arrive at (assuming all wavefunctions are normalized):

\begin{align}
\tag{1}
  \langle \phi\vert\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1\vert\phi\rangle\langle \phi\vert\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2\vert\phi\rangle + \langle \phi\vert\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2\vert\phi\rangle\langle \phi\vert\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1\vert\phi\rangle  &= 2\langle \phi\vert\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2\vert\phi\rangle\langle \phi\vert\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1\vert\phi\rangle \\
&=2|c_1|^2|c_2|^2 \tag{2}\\
&\le2.\tag{3}
\end{align}

In the case where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are ***positive*** and real-valued, which does actually happen quite often in quantum mechanics, you'd get:

\begin{align}
2(c_1c_2)^2 ~~~~~&\textrm{vs.} ~~~~~2 c_1c_2\tag{4}  \\
\end{align}

Then since $c_1 c_2 \le 1$, you would be correct that the left side is $\le$ the right side. However there's cases where the inequality is *not* true, for example:

#### $c_1$ purely real and $c_2$ purely imaginary:

The right-hand side (of your inequality in Eq. 2) becomes:

$$
c_1c_2^* + c_1^*c_2 = c_1(c_2 - c_2) = 0\tag{5},
$$

but the left-hand side is bigger than 0 because $|c_2|^2>0.$

#### $c_1$ and $c_2$ have different signs:

The right-side (of your inequality in Eq. 2) can be negative while the left-side is positive.

Comment: Let $c_1 = a + ib$ and $c_2 = u + iv$ then $c_1 c_2^* + c_1^* c_2 = (a+ib)(u-iv) + (a-ib)(u+iv) = 2(au+bv) \in \mathbb{R} $.

Comment: @KAJ226 good point.

Comment: This is completely wrong.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Which part.

Comment: All except for the one you added after I posted my answer.  (And the one you added after my comment above, changing "real-valued" to "positive and real-valued".)

Comment: Well, for instance, (5) cannot be larger than 2.  And just because it *can*, doesn't mean the inequality were correct.  ---  And yes, the bottomline of the *last* paragraph is correct, and that of the one where you added *positive* later on.  ---  I think it should be clear that "completely wrong" refers to the result (or the proof thereof), not every step.

Comment: Also, if you don't like people commenting on your posts, maybe SE is not the right platform for you.  If people downvote and don't comment, were that better?

Comment: I never said that I don't like "people" commenting on my posts. I don't like rude and abusive comments that violate the SE Code of Conduct, and yours have too often been of that nature.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch You said that "all" is "wrong". So you pointing out an "instance" that is wrong, is not enough. If "the last paragraph is correct", then why did you write "This is completely wrong" (1 hour ago) long after that last paragraph was already there for so long before your comment?

Comment: Ok, let me be more precise: Your post contains an odd number of sign errors.  (I also notice that whenever I point out sth. wrong, you go out and edit it out.  Ultimately, your post will read "This is wrong, just take $c_1>0$ and $c_2<0$." ;) )

Comment: @NorbertSchuch What sign errors?

Comment: It was a joke. Should I explain it?  (See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171748/dirac-and-sign-errors-in-odd-number-of-places)

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong, just take $c_1>0$ and $c_2<0$.